# This HttpRequestMessage Headers are assignable even that they are { get; } only

Tags: oop, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

Why do I get about this assignment into `Headers` this error

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage()
{
    Headers = default
};
```

`Property or indexer 'property' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only`

And it is the same even if i assign `null`.

And for the following code i dont get it, ain't it also an assignment of value to `Headers` property ?

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage()
{
    Headers = {}
};
```

Answer (score 2):

After some research it seems that if a property is read-only, items can be added to it using `{}`, this is the meaning of this operator, this is not an assignment to the property reference. for example:

```
public class ItemsContainer
{
    public List<string> Items { get; } = new List<string> { "a" };
}
```

This code will producde:

```
ItemsContainer itemsContainer = new ItemsContainer()
{
    Items = { "b" }
};

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(',', itemsContainer.Items));
```

Will have result of:

```
a,b
```

Which mean that it only adds to the collection.

If we change the implimitaitiom of `ItemsContainer` to:

```
public class ItemsContainer
{
    public List<string> Items { get; }
}
```

For the same code a `NullReferenceException` will be thrown because you try to add to a collection which is not initialized and have a `null` value.

More info:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#object-initializers-with-collection-read-only-property-initialization

Answer (score 1):

`{}` is a [collection initializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#collection-initializers):

```
int[] fooBar = { };
```

I cannot find a proof that [empty collection initializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#collection-initializers) `{}` can be assigned to readonly property which has reference type.

However, this code is valid:

```
public class FooBar
{
    public object MyProperty { get; }
}

var foo = new FooBar()
{
    MyProperty = { }
};
```

Comment: Actually it is written here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#collection-initializers

Answer (score 0):

You can't. That is what read-only properties are for. You cannot the change the actual reference, but you can change the value itself. Based on what the concrete type allows.

If you want to have the headers empty (which it looks like from your example), you just use `request.Headers.Clear()`. And other methods alike if you want to alter/add/etc. headers.

Comment: What is the difference between `Headers = default` and `Headers = {}`, What is the meaning of `{}` this is not a constructor of the same things ?.

I don't want necessarily to have empty `Headers` it was just example i just don't understand why is the different in the assignments


@Christian.K

Comment: If it is a reference type so the value is null or reference when you assign, I didn't understand either this "You cannot the change the actual reference, but you can change the value itself"